# Node-RED works on localhost, but "Error: Lost connection to server" on Azure

Tags: node-red

I have a local clone of the git repo for node-red on Windows. Runs great locally.  I then deploy this to Azure (which requires a minor port change) and the app runs on Azure, BUT, I am seeing the following behavior:

- Error: Lost connection to server is constantly displayed
- Debug tab shows nothing if you try a hello-world inject, etc

I have tried http and https. I have no idea what is special about this applications requirements, it is a simple azure deployment.

Ideas?

Comment: Does Azure support Websockets?

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on my comment.

The errors are normally associated with the Node-RED console not being able to create a websockets connection to the server.

It looks like you may have to enable Websockets for a site hosted on Azure:

http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2013/11/14/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites/